# Does the Facebook app need to be installed to use Facebook for Game Developers?

Tags: facebook

I just learned about [Facebook for Game Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games). I would like to know if I need to have the Facebook app installed in my phone to use Facebook for Game Developers (like I need to install Google play games services in android).

Comment: Your question #1 is fine. It has an answer. Question #2 is just opinion-based. Maybe edit this only to inclue the first question.

Comment: @Almo I think based on our policies here, this question is fine: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @user1517108 Where did you find out about the rate limit for Facebook API calls? I can't find this on their web site, and 200 seems extremely low.

Comment: @piojo: My Error: forgot to mention per 60 mins. Also the api are not monitored per user, rather per ap pbasis: number of user of app*200 per minute. I had read it yesterday, FB came out last year around Oct with the rate limit. I cant get that link again

Comment: Pro/con lists in general don't fit here, and pro/con lists for specific software *definitely* don't (as they're effectively answering a "which technology to use" question. I removed that part of the question. The (original) first question, as Almo points out, is perfectly fine.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Did you read the guidelines I linked? The question you removed appears to perfectly fit the definition of a "constructive subjective question".

Comment: @JoshPetrie, I didn't ask for opinion or preference, what I asked for was features comparison. I think piojo answer and my comment on it are good examples. Questions are not just about resolving the query but also about helping someone else. By the edit, the crux of the question is diluted IMO.

Comment: Asking for "pros and cons" is the very definition of off-topic here.

Comment: "Feature comparisons" are *not* on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The game can use the Facebook APIs without facebook installed on the player's device.
2. I haven't used Google Play, but Facebook is unable to query the information of any friend that's not also using the game. Requesting the friend list will return an empty list, for instance, until another friend installs the game. There is an API for inviting friends to install the game, but I don't know how effective that is in the real world. (I've never accepted an invitation to play a game with a friend.) If you call the API that purports to send messages and requests to the user's friends (assuming the friends have not yet installed the game), the messages will show an invitation to install/play instead of the actual content.

Comment: Another important point that I noted is that one can save their game in google play games on google cloud, whereas in facebook it has to be in ones' own servers (though can be routed thru FB APIs). Google kind of provides a cleaner method.